# What is difference between .bowerrc file and bower.json file

Tags: bower

I'm working on a project and its root directory has both files:

- .bowerrc
- bower.json

They both seem to configure `bower`, they both seem to use JSON, and my project has both files. But how are they different?

Comment: bower.json is for client-side packages and bowerrc is for server-side packages.

Comment: I dont think thats right

Comment: bowerrc controls dirs... that is server-side no? https://zellwk.com/blog/bower/

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "server-side" ? My laptop is a client, right? My laptop has `.bowerrc` on it, which my `bower` program uses to run. And while it may configure some things about where to get bower packages (like the registry location), 1) it also configures things about client side (like the install location) and 2) I still think "server-side" might be a misnomer.

Comment: your browser is client-side, css and js are client side. HTML is client-side. Creating directories on a machine etc or running source files is not. Probably better ways to explain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bower site explains the difference:

- [bower.json](https://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/#bowerjson) exists inside of a **package**. (at the root directory of a package). A package is contained code which other developers/packages can use. So if you make your own package, you need a bower.json. If you use another package, it must have a bower.json
- [.bowerrc](https://bower.io/docs/config/) exists either at the "user's home folder" (aka `~`) and/or the "global folder" (aka `/`). This file configures how the bower program (the **command-line** utility) will work. The configurations in this file are merged with configurations you can specify other ways (i.e. arguments via the command-line) so bower knows how to run

[This repository](https://github.com/bower/spec) also explains the difference (**emphasis** added):

> - With [bower.json](https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/json.md) for **project** configuration (like package.json or Gemfile)
> - With [configuration variables](https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/config.md) for execution **in general** (like **command-line** flags)

Notice that "configuration" can be expressed in the `.bowerrc` file.